# Without Recursion giving memory error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, fibonacci

I got to know that memoization is better approach for playing with Fibonacci series. Today i wrote the program in this way--

```
    private void printFibonacci(int lengthOfSeries) {

    int lastNumb = 1;
    int secondLastNumb = 1;

    List<Integer> fabArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (lengthOfSeries == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number to print series.");

    } else {

        fabArray.add(secondLastNumb);
        fabArray.add(lastNumb);

        while (fabArray.size() < lengthOfSeries) {

            lastNumb = fabArray.get(fabArray.size() - 1);
            secondLastNumb = fabArray.get(fabArray.size() - 2);

            fabArray.add(lastNumb + secondLastNumb);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fabArray);
}
```

This is working fine. But when the input number is high (say 100,000,000), its throwing `outOfMemoryerror`. And its throwing error at line where printing List.

Can anybody please give some suggestion to make it powerful.

Comment: Maybe it ran out of memory because the input is high...?

Comment: you are memoizing all the values, when you really only need the 2 last. you can either only save those 2, or use a circular buffer of size 2.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc yes you are right. That i want to diagnose and fix it.

Comment: @njzk2 Can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not generating correct values for bigger numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: @Arfeen Try doing this over and over: `c = a + b; a = b; b = c;` ... cogito's answer does exactly that.

Comment: The _n_'th Fibonacci number is approximately equal to `Math.pow(1.61803398,n)/Math.sqrt(5)`.  If `lengthOfSeries` is 100,000,000, the last number in the series will require over 69 million bits.  That's just a little too large to store in an `int` or `long`.  (Or even in a `double`.)  So you may want to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ajb Thank you. I got my mistake. Need to rethink of the i implemented.

Comment: From a quick calculation, if you want Fibonacci numbers that fit in an `int`, the maximum series length is 46; in a `long`, 92; in a `double`, about 1473.  Those values might be off by a couple.

Comment: @ajb That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the growth of the ArrayList that is causing the OutOfMemoryError, and you don't need to either print the list or terminate your loop.  The following code should have no problems with memory:

```
 private void printFibonacci(int lengthOfSeries) {

    int lastNumb = 1;
    int secondLastNumb = 1;
    int count = 2;

    if (lengthOfSeries == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number to print series.");

    } else {

        System.out.print("1, 1");

        while (count < lengthOfSeries) {
            int next = lastNumb + secondLastNumb;
            System.out.print(", " + next);
            secondLastNumb = lastNumb;
            lastNumb = next;
            //Updated
            count = count+1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of this kind of algorithms, they're very memory-hungry. Also using int/Integer for it is a very bad idea as you'll quickly run out of Integer capacity (2*10^32 -1). Probably you want doubles, but still there is a limit of how far you can go.

Answer (score 0):

100 million Integers takes about 400 million bytes.

This may well be larger than your JVMs default maximum heap size. Try adding command line switches to allocate more memory.

Some indications here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rt.doc.20%2Fdiag%2Fappendixes%2Fdefaults.html

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, a trivial implementation would be:

```
int[] fabArray = new int[] {1, 1, 0};
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfSeries; i++) {
    fabArray[2] = fabArray[1] + fabArray[0];
    System.out.print(fabArray[0] + ", ");
    fabArray[0] = fabArray[1];
    fabArray[1] = fabArray[2];
}
// End of line
System.out.println();
```